# How to retrieve the django user profile object in a view?

Tags: django

Is there an easy way to access the user's profile in a view, something like `user.profile.my_field`?

Answer (score 3):

OK, worked it out. It's `user.get_profile.my_field`.

Comment: You forgot the most important part of this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile